# Is the usage "My heart jumps all over the place" correct? And what does it mean if it does?

Tags: idiom-meaning

Recently, I have come across this

> I looked at your face and **my heart jumped all over the place**.

I tried to look it up in dictionaries, and the only entry I could find is here

https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/someone-s-heart-leaps-jumps-quickens

According to this, it turns out that "jump" there meant "quicken". I don't think it will go well with "all over the place", but I am not sure if the usage is correct or not. Could you please tell me?

And even if such usage exists, is it correct to use the description of "one's heart jumps all over the place" to talk about the feelings of a lovestruck person?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is unusual to include "all over the place". If you say "I looked at your face and my heart jumped" that is enough. After all, your heart remains exactly where it is. Sometimes you will see "my heart skipped a beat."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"My heart jumped all over the place," most likely means, "my heart was beating erratically." Whereas typically your heart will beat to a rhythm, a lovestruck person's heart might beat faster, slower, to no perfect rhythm, skip a beat, etc. and "jump all over the place."

Probably not a very common saying, but I think it makes sense in context.